# Queues of Arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I'm working on a program that orders jobs for three different people, so I used queues because the jobs need to be done first in, first out. The jobs are arrays storing three different strings. This is the relevant code I have at the moment.

```
Queue<String[]> MMT1Jobs  = new LinkedList<String[]>();
Queue<String[]> MMT2Jobs  = new LinkedList<String[]>();
Queue<String[]> MMT3Jobs  = new LinkedList<String[]>();
//job array layout should look like this [registration number][grid reference][who is assign to the job]
String[] MMT1CurrentJob = new String[3];
String[] MMT2CurrentJob = new String[3];
String[] MMT3CurrentJob = new String[3];
String[] MMT1LastJob = new String[3];
String[] MMT2LastJob = new String[3];
String[] MMT3LastJob = new String[3];
String[] justScanned = new String[3];
//check if there is any Jobs open
File jobsOpenFile = new File("JOBS-OPEN.txt");
if(jobsOpenFile.exists())
{
  //File exists
  Scanner jobsFile = new Scanner(jobsOpenFile);
  while(jobsFile.hasNext == true)
  {
    justScanned[1] = jobsFile.next();//registration number
    justScanned[2] = jobsFile.next();//grid reference
    justScanned[3] = jobsFile.nextLine();//who is assigned and end of line
    //assign who get what jobs
    if(justScanned[3].equals("1"))
    {
      MMt1Jobs.add(justScanned[]);//error here
    }
    else if(justScanned[3].equals("2"))
    {
      MMt2Jobs.add(justScanned[]);//error here
    }
    else
    {
      MMt3Jobs.add(justScanned[]);//error here
    }
  }
}
```

I'm currently getting "error: '.class' expected" on the lines that I've marked. Sorry if this is a simple fix but I'm new to java. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you don't need the array brackets(`[]`) in your errornous statements:

```
  MMt1Jobs.add(justScanned[]);//error here
```

replace this with

```
  MMt1Jobs.add(justScanned)
```

No need for that extra `[]`.

`[]` is a syntax part of array declaration time to specify length of `array`.

Therefore, you need not use it while adding the `array` to a `list`. Just use variable name.

Comment: Was just about to post the same answer. You were super quick!:) +1! But can you just add a bit more of explanation why it is not needed?! Would be good for the OP to understand why it's throwing the error.

Comment: @Juned. Added some description. Please review and feel free to revert, If you feel it is an invalid edit.

Comment: @RJ Thanks for adding more descripiton. It is nice to see people trying to improve some one else answer instead of adding their own. Really appreciate both you and Suresh.

Comment: Thanks for both the answer and the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

May be a very silly thing to point out, but if this was copy-pasted then shouldn't your "MMt1Jobs" be "MMT1Jobs", with a capital "t"?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I wanted to leave a comment on the post, but I don't have the reputation and couldn't find another way to point this out to the user as important as it seems.  Sorry about that.